# Perl regex substitution replacing 1 too many characters

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I'm reasonably competent in perl regex substitutions, but I'm getting kind of rusty and this is something I don't usually do.  It's to escape an & character for XML but prevent replacing &'s in already-escaped characters.  It seems to work fine except it deletes or replaces the character to the right of it. What am I missing?

```
$str =~ s/&[^amp;|lt;|gt;|quot;|#39;]/&amp;/g;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mistaking the negated character class for [negative look-ahead](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).

Your regex really means:

```
/&[^#39aglmopqtu;|]/ # mixed a few letters and removed duplicates
```

but you *meant*:

```
/&(?!amp;|lt;|gt;|quot;|#39;)/
```

The square bracktes denote character classes, not grouping!

If you really want to avoid matching XML entities, you should rather use a regex like

```
m{& (?! (?:
   (?:\#[0-9]+)
  |(?:\#x[0-9a-fA-F]+)
  |(?:[lg]t|amp|apos|quot) # predefined XML entities
); )}x
```

(compare the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent)) and somehow add all entities that are declared by your document, or a referenced DTD.

Comment: Hmm...I have some catching up to do!  Both the solutions work.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need zero-width negative look-ahead. Something like

```
$str =~ s/&(?!amp;|lt;|gt;|quot;|#39;)/&amp;/g;
```